# Error in setting value to char ** variable c++

Tags: c++, variables, char

I'm using DEV-C++ for c++ programming.
I want to use a char** variable in my program and the code i use for setting value is:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {

    char **arg;
        *arg="oo";


        return 0;
    }
```

but when i run the program, i get a window that says:
project.exe has stopped working.
Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: If you had a `int *arg;`, would `*arg = 5;` be correct?

Comment: no,i tested it and i got that window

Comment: Do you understand why the code in my previous comment is bad?

Comment: This is because, no memory has been allocated to the array of pointers arg.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ we can directly assign numbers to any variable(int, float, long ...)
But for strings we need to use [String](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) functions like `strcpy()` or we can use `= operator` overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char x[10]= "static string";
    char *arg[10]; 
    arg[0] = malloc(sizeof("oo"));
    strcpy(*arg, "oo");
    arg[1] = malloc(sizeof("pp"));
    strcpy(*(arg+1), "pp");
    arg[2] = malloc(sizeof("pp"));
    strcpy(arg[2], "qq");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically making a "Pointer to (pointer to (a **character**))" and then trying to store a **string** in a double pointer which requires a (pointer to a **character**). 
This how you use a double pointer for characters :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char **arg;

char a='o';
char *b = &a ; //'b' stores address of a char variable 'a'
arg = &b; //'arg' stores an address of a pointer to char 

cout << **arg;
return 0;
}
```